# Probability of getting exactly one correct card when distributing n cards among n people

Tags: probability

If I distribute n cards among n people and each person can get one correct card matched his identity.
What is the probability that only one person would get the correct card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose one person to get the correct card, done in n ways.
Then distribute the remaining cards such that the (n-1) people do not have their correct cards. You will then need to apply the formula for derangements here I think.

After that, divide by n! to obtain the required probability.